# Why were Symfony 3 unit tests moved out of the actual bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing

I never really write any tests because I usually have to work with low budgets. So I usually just delete the demo files.
However, I noticed that the test directory was moved from /src/MyBundle/Test in Symfony 2 to /tests in Symfony 3 and I wonder why?

Bundles are, or at least I thought they are, potentially "decoupable" components in an application. This means it's always possible to run/work with the same bundle in another Symfony "runtime" with little to no effort.

So, moving the tests directory out of its related bundle into the root directory doesn't make any sense for me. Making an independent piece of software dependent/incomplete for no reason.
It actually makes me feel like I completely misunderstood the concept of bundles in Symfony.

I also noticed that Symfony tutorials started a few years ago to force their users to move their templates into /app/Resources. When I learned it, they had the templates in their related bundles which seems much cleaner for me. Why should I ever move anything outside if I already have everything bundled (!) in a single directory. Maybe I have some problems with the translation, but in german, a "bundle" is 1 single unit. If you split a bundle, you get 2, but not a half.

I usually see Symfony as a configured runtime for my bundles, so I don't touch anything outside /src besides composer.json, AppKernel or config files.

Well, I may admit that the bundle may react different based on its environment - but unit tests shouldn't even rely on context if I got them right.

Even if you see the AppBundle as a special, context related one - it's still an inconsistent development style when some files can be found there, where others can be found in a completely different place. At least the AppBundle shouldn't be a bundle then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tests**

I think that this change was made just to move out the tests from the actual `src` folder. It is kind of best practice in other programming languages like JAVA, because tests are not a part of your actual source code. Test also are not included in the final artifact (take composer.phar as example) to minimize its size.

The test directory structure is composed out of bundles directories with their related tests so still have separated tests for bundles:

```
tests/
├── AppBundle/
│   ├── Entity
│   │   └── UserTest.php
│   ├── Service
│   ├── Other
│   └── Etc
├── OtherBundle/
│   ├── Controller
│   └── Entity
└── EtcBundle/
```

**Templates**

As far as template are concerned, it is way easier for designers to find all the needed templates when they are in a single directory.

Anyway, that's my two cents.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I get it now. I have to admit I'm not that far experienced to talk big, but imo a bundle is kind of an application on it's own, so everything related should be inside its directory. This includes tests as well as templates. But if you actually spend the time writing tests, I guess moving them back into the bundle before preparing it for reuse is probably the easiest part.

Comment: If the bundle is shared (which you get from composer etc) everything you say will be true. If you have several local bundles such separation no longer matters.

Comment: You're right. When thinking about it again, I've never really had any bundle where I didn't knew from the beginning that it will be reused. Anyway, I like to handle all bundles as I would reuse them, even if it's completely senseless. I'll accept your answer in a few hours if nothing changes.

Comment: Hope i helped. Good luck coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you check the composer.json files, you could see that the Tests directory is (auto)loaded only for the dev environment so in a production system you don't have this files loaded too. 
As example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
    "files": [
        "app/AppKernel.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": { "Tests\\": "tests/" }
},
```

This will speed up autoloading in your application.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So this change was mainly made bc of performance / size / limitations of composer and not necessarily in favor of better software design?

Comment: hi @sboesch I think the main benefit is about better design and code understanding. I add only the side about the autoloading mechanism behaviour.

Comment: Somewhat disappointing, as the design point doesn't make much sense to me whereas the one about performance pretty much does. Whatever, I should not bring everything into question... Thank you anyway @Matteo!

Comment: IMHO is more clean in terms of clean code and Why not, better autoloader performance!

Comment: It's all about performance here. Less number of classes speeds up the autoload process.

Answer (score 0):

It's because in Symfony 3 there's a separation between application bundles and reusable bundles:

> There are two types of bundles:
>
> - Application-specific bundles: only used to build your application;
> - Reusable bundles: meant to be shared across many projects.
>
> This article is all about how to structure your reusable bundles so that
>   they're easy to configure and extend. Many of these recommendations do
>   not apply to application bundles because you'll want to keep those as
>   simple as possible.

You can learn more in [bundle best practices in Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html).